# Algorithm to find which hashes in a list match another hash the fastest? (this is complicated to explain on title)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, pattern-matching

Explaining with words when 2 hashes would match is complicated, so, see the example:
Hash patterns are stored in a list like: *(I'm using JavaScript for notation)*

```
pattern:[
    0:{type:'circle', radius:function(n){ return n>10; }},
    1:{type:'circle', radius:function(n){ return n==2; }},
    2:{type:'circle', color:'blue', radius:5},
    ... etc]

var test = {type:'circle', radius:12};
```

test should match with pattern 0 because pattern[0].type==test.type && pattern.radius(test.radius)==true.

So, trying with words, a hash matches a pattern if every of it's values is either equal of those of the pattern or returns true when applied as a function.

My question is: is there an algorithm to find all patterns that match certain hash without testing all of them?

Comment: You want to know if it is a clone?

Comment: Kind of, with the exception that hashes like {a:function(x){ return x==1; }} should match {a:1} even if they are not a clone. Also I want an algorithm that, given a hash and a (big) list of hashes, finds which matches, without testing all hashes on the list.

Comment: But you cannot know every element without usiing a O(n).

Comment: You could rework your pattern hash so that you lookup by type to get list of numbers and functions

Comment: ARoughly how many patterns will there be? If it is small, it may not be worth optimizing.

Comment: walrii, thousands. Chris Moutray, how?

Comment: Note: I would like to know the answer to the problem without the functions too. It is probably a different approach so I posted in a different thread. If you know how to answer it, please look on my user page.

Comment: Have you considered a decision tree instead of a hash? Or is the pattern list too dynamic?

Comment: It is not very dynamic, but I'm not sure in how to represent such three as some values could be functions. I have made a representation which I guess is faster than O(n), but it is ugly, so I would like to know if there are more elegant and faster solutions, as I'm running it millions of times a second.

Comment: If there are common fields that are always values, such as `type` in your example, you can have separate lists for each value, eliminating the need to look at values that will not match. You can have an additional list that has a function that must always be checked.

Comment: So, you mean something like: {type:{circle:[0,1]}}, which would mean patterns 0 and 1 could match something with {type:'circle'}, so I limit the testing to those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a dynamic, recursive, decision tree structure like the following.

```
decision:[
    field:'type',
    values:[
        'circle': <another decision structure>,
        'square': 0, // meaning it matched, return this value
        'triangle': <another decision structure>
    ],
    functions:[
        function(n){ return n<12;}: <another decision structure>,
        function(n){ return n>12;}: <another decision structure>
    ],
    missing: <another decision structure>
]
```

Algorithm on d (a decision structure):

```
if test has field d.field
    if test[d.field] in d.values
        if d.values[test[d.field]] is a decision structure
            recurse using the new decision structure
        else
            yield d.values[test[d.field]]
    foreach f => v in d.functions
        if f(test[d.field])
            if v is a decision structure
                recurse using the new decision structure
            else
                yield v
else if d.missing is present
    if d.missing is a decision structure
        recurse using the new decision structure
    else
        yield d.missing
else
    No match
```

Comment: I kind of get it now. Just two questions: would that structure get too big after 1000 or so patterns? And what would be the algorithm to insert a new pattern?

Comment: Yes it will get very big, if you were to print it in this format. But it is optimized to only check what it needs to instead of checking everything--it should be much faster. Dynamic addition of a pattern is a bit more difficult. You traverse the same way, keeping track of which fields have been handled. You then add a new entry to d.values or d.functions, or create d.missing. When you add a new entry, you create a new nested decision structure for the unhandled fields in the pattern. Do it by hand a few times and it will be clear.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much. Can I ask here again if I miss something?